# Determine region of convergence of $\prod_{n=1}^{\infty} ( 1-(1-cos(z/n)) $

Tags: complex-analysis, convergence-divergence, infinite-product

This question was asked in my complex analysis assignment and I was unable to solve it. So I am posting here as assignement might not will be discussed.

> Find the region of Convergence for $\prod_{n=1}^{\infty}\cos(z/n) $.

Attempt: I wrote the given product as $\prod_{n=1}^{\infty} ( 1-(1-\cos(z/n)) $. The term  $\lim_{n\to \infty}|( 1-(1-\cos(z/n)) | \to 0$ ( If question was about $\sin(z/n)$ then the corresponding sum would go to 1 and from that it could be deduced that Corresponding product of $\sin(z)$ would diverge everywhere. )

But , this argument  certainly can't  be used for cos and I am unable to think of any other result which I can use. So, please help.

Thanks!

Comment: use that $1-1-\cos(z/n)$ is about $z^2/(2n^2)$ for large enough $n$ and $z$ fixed (or in a compact set) to show normal convergence of the product to an entire function with zeroes where factors have zeroes (note that these are $n \pi/2 + 2kn \pi$ so $m\pi/2+2k\pi$ with various finiite multiplicities)